# Inline conditional in Jade?

Tags: pug

I am passing an object, `school`, into my edit form and want to set one of these options as selected. School has a property `focus` such that for JavaScript `school.focus = 1`, for Python `school.focus = 2`, and for Ruby on Rails `school.focus = 3`)

**How could I write an inline conditional to set one of these options as 'selected'?**

```
//- Focus
div(data-role='fieldcontain')
  fieldset(data-role='controlgroup')
    label(for='focus') Focus
      select(name='focus')
        option(value='JavaScript') JavaScript
        option(value='Python') Python
        option(value='Ruby on Rails') Ruby on Rails
```

I have gotten this type of inline conditional to work when there is an assignment (value=):

```
//- School Name
    div(data-role='fieldcontain')
      fieldset(data-role='controlgroup')
        label(for='school_name') School Name
          input(id='school_name',type='text', value=(school ? '#{school.school_name}' :     ''),placeholder='School name here',name='school_name')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately for you, Jade is awesome and you don't need to use a ternary at all. KISS.

```
div
  fieldset
    label Focus
      select
        option(value='JavaScript', selected=(school.focus == 1)) JavaScript
        option(value='Python', selected=(school.focus == 2)) Python
        option(value='Ruby on Rails', selected=(school.focus == 3)) Ruby on Rails
```

So, if `locals.school.focus` is `2`, then you'd end up with this markup:

```
<div>
  <fieldset>
    <label>Focus
      <select>
        <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
        <option value="Python" selected="selected">Python</option>
        <option value="Ruby on Rails">Ruby on Rails</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Demo @ http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Razge/

I recommend refactoring slightly to separate the values and labels from the markup, so that you can have Jade iterate over them for you, but that's the general idea.

---

**N.B.** you can omit a label's `for` attribute entirely if the label is the parent of the element you want to label. [In spec-speak, that's:](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element)

> If the for attribute is not specified, but the label element has a labelable element descendant, then the first such descendant in tree order is the label element's labeled control.

...all of which to say: in your case, that label's `for` attribute is superfluous and you can get rid of it.

Comment: Works perfectly and thanks for the fast response! Could you provide an example for what you mean when you say to separate the values and labels from the markup?

Comment: Put them into an array, like `[{label: 'JavaScript', value: 'JavaScript'}, {label: 'Python', value: 'Python'}, {...}]` and iterate over that array to generate the `<option>` elements. Of course, if the option's value is always the same as its text, as your example suggests is the case, you can omit the `value` attribute entirely, too.

Comment: @user949300 the documentation does indeed suck, but I don't think a downvote is espectially constructive here... http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwv4X.png